# How to transfer cell information to another and making sure it matched up to column names in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have got an excel document which has a list of all client names, and addresses. I would like to transfer all the cells to a new cell using a formula. The problem is that the cells I want to move to the new cells have a few different column names. I want a code that will transfer the cells to its appropriate column name, but if the column does not exist then I want to add a column to say 'not found'.

Comment: Can you please explain more?... This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the formula you would need for this would involve index() and match(), with iferror(), but it's not possible to provide a specific solution without a specific example.